# Codeiginiter 2 view show after form validation

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

i use codeiginiter and stencil template for my code and after form validation run it should load view if validation run false but it show 2 VIEW (1 as normal form and other it show validation ) any though? thank you

```
$this->stencil->title('สร้างใบจองทัวร์');
    $this->stencil->layout('booktour_layout');
    $this->stencil->css('font-awesome');
    $this->stencil->paint('booktour_create');

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('programe_name', 'ชื่อโปรแกรม', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('tour_code', 'ชื่อโปรแกรม', 'required');

    if(isset($_POST['programe_name'])) {

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {

    $this->stencil->paint('booktour_create');

    }
    else
    {

        echo "<script>alert('success');</script>";  

    }       
    }
```

Comment: Remove conditional `if(isset($_POST['programe_name'])) {/* but leave this between */}` and try again.

Comment: @Tpojka now it show 2 form at pageload instant , very weird coz other controller of same project work just fine??

Comment: Remove first `$this->stencil->paint('booktour_create');` (third line) and see.

Comment: @Tpojka anything don't show at all

Comment: Sorry for guessing. Didn't use stencil yet.